# set defalut value to custom java swing component property

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to create a custom button.

```
public class MyButton extends JButton implements PropertyChangeListener {

}
```

and I want to set a default value to some property in this button. I.E. if user not set any value as **foreground_color** I want to set it as Color.RED

if user set any color as **foreground_color** the button should ignore the default color.

is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can add a constructor to your `MyButton` class that sets the default values. Of course these can be overwritten later with `myButton.setForeground()` etc.:

```java
public MyButton() {
    super();
    setForeground(Color.RED);
    // ... 
}
```

If you want to keep any special constructors from `JButton` (e.g. the one that takes a string for a button text), you can of course modify this or add another one:

```java
public MyButton(String text) {
    super(text);
    setDefaults();
}

private void setDefaults() {
    setForeground(Color.RED);
    // ... more defaults ...
}
```

Comment: You might want to overwrite `setForeground` to check if the backgrounds has been set to `null` in which case you probably want to revert back to your default value.